# JQuery EasyUI TreeGrid Dynamic Data Loading

Tags: java, jquery, json, jquery-easyui

I'm new to jQuery and am not quite sure how to do the following:

I'm using EasyUI TreeGrid and want to display dynamic data rather than providing static data from a .json file. Currently, the code I'm using is as follows:

```
$(function(){
        $('#test').treegrid({
              url:'treegrid_data.json',
```

and so on. Instead, is there any way I can pass an ArrayList or bean object or something directly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. This way, I'm providing static data stored in 'treegrid_data.json' file. Instead, I'd like to pass dynamic data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...instead of pointing to a static json file, specify the url as `url: 'dynamic.jsp'` or `url: 'dynamic.java'` pointing towards a jsp or servlet respectively(since we are developing a web application). In that page simply get the json string, say, as an attribute and print it using `out.println(jsonString)`. Do not include any HTML tags whatsoever or you won't get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

instead of getting the static json file.. point the url to a page where you are getting a dynamic value.. say  dynamic.php

```
 url:'dynamic.php',
 ....
```

and do your stuff like mysql connect.. or getting the dynamic datas in dynamic.php and return it as json....

**dynamic.php**

```
//do your stuff like getting dynamic datas in array..

$dynamicarray= $yourDynamicDataArray..
echo json_encode($dynamicarray);
```

this should do...

Comment: How can I achieve the same using Java? Should I use a simple java class containing a method which returns an ArrayList?

Comment: I haven't checked whether it works for a simple java class. Thanks for your help anyway.